# How to pass data from activity to RecyclerViewAdapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been used Intent to save the data that I want to pass.. this is in login page..

```
String name = etUsername.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Posting.class);
        intent.putExtra("myname", name);
```

this username I want to pass it from login page to my RecyclerView layout by clicking on Add Button in Posting class:

By clicking on AddButton the username should appear in each CardView.

here is the posting class that have AddButton:

```
public class Posting extends ActionBarActivity {


private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;

EditText nameField;
Button btnAdd;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posting);
    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);


    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);

    Toolbar my_toolbars = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbars);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title);



    linearLayoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);


    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namefield);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String newName = nameField.getText().toString();

            if (!newName.equals("")) {


                myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0, newName);


                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String name = intent.getStringExtra("myname");
                textView.setText(name);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

and this is the layout of the cardView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5sp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:text="i" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

I want to pass it from login page to this page through TextView with id="username".

how can this be done?

Comment: add a string field in adapter constructor, and while creating the instance of adapter, pass that name.

Comment: this is the constructor
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context){
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

what should I do?

Comment: in addition to context, add a string variable in constructor

Comment: ok I done with it .... what else should I do?

Comment: now in constructor of adapter you have name, use it

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a beginner.... can you explain more please ?

Comment: create a member string field in adapter and assign the value you are getting in the constructor. Then use it where you want in adapter.

Answer (score 1):

```
//in posting Activity
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String newName = nameField.getText().toString();

        if (!newName.equals("")) {

        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,newName);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    }
});
```

---

```
In RecyclerViewAdapter
//Create Constructor like below:
String name;
Activity context;
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity activity,String newName){
 this.context=activity;
 this.name= newName;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int    position) {
  holder.username.setText(name); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by username here? holder.username.setText(name); because it give an error

Comment: its textview in the adapter class